# Wait for user response Role

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, discord.js

```
    message.channel.send(`\`DBump Reminders\` Have been enabled`)
    message.channel.send(`\`DBump Reminders\` What role would you like to ping? If None response with N`)

    const returnedMessageContent = await new Promise((resolve) => {
  const messageCollector = message.channel.createMessageCollector({ time: 60000 });




  messageCollector.on('collect', (msg) => {
    if (msg.author.id !== message.author.id) return;
    if(msg.content === 'N') return message.channel.send('Enabled without Ping')
    console.log(message.mentions.roles.first())
    const role = message.mentions.roles.first()
    if(msg.content.replace(/\D+/g, '') !== role.id){
   message.channel.send(`No Role was Found`)
  } else {
   message.channel.send(`${role} was set as the bump ping`)
  }


    messageCollector.stop();
    resolve(msg.content);
  });

  messageCollector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
    if (reason === 'time') {
      message.channel.send('Time ran out, please call the command again');
      resolve(null);
    }
  });
 });
```

I'm trying to wait for user response however It can't read mentioned roles

[Mursy] Unhandled Rejection:  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
at MessageCollector. (C:\Users\aweso\Desktop\Mursy - Copy\Mursy\Files\Commands\Test\test.js:36:49)
at MessageCollector.emit (node:events:390:28)
at MessageCollector.handleCollect (C:\Users\aweso\Desktop\Mursy - Copy\Mursy\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\Collector.js:109:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

this is the error I keep getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is clearly in your collector

It should be `msg.mentions.roles.first()`

```js
    messageCollector.on('collect', (msg) => {
          if (msg.author.id !== message.author.id) return;
          if(msg.content === 'N') return message.channel.send('Enabled without Ping')
          console.log(msg.mentions.roles.first())

          const role = msg.mentions.roles.first()
          if(msg.content.replace(/\D+/g, '') !== role.id){
         message.channel.send(`No Role was Found`)
        } else {
         message.channel.send(`${role} was set as the bump ping`)
        }
    
    })
```

Comment: Yeah I realized that after 2 hours of posting this